# Is it posible for a React function to keep calling itself until state value changes?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web-audio-api

I'm trying to replicate on React a metronome built with Vue. Basically the `play` function keeps calling itself while `playing` is true. Here is the Vue code:

```
data() {
    return {
      playing: false,
      audioContext: null,
      audioBuffer: null,
      currentTime: null
    }
},
mounted() {
    this.initContext();
},
methods: {
    toggle()
      if (!this.playing) {
        this.currentTime = this.audioContext.currentTime;
        this.playing = true;
        this.play();
      } else {
        this.playing = false;
      }
    },
    play() {
      this.currentTime += 60 / this.$store.state.tempo;
      const source = this.audioContext.createBufferSource();
      source.buffer = this.audioBuffer;
      source.connect(this.audioContext.destination);
      source.onended = this.playing ? this.play : "";
      source.start(this.currentTime);
    },
    async initContext() {
      this.audioContext = new AudioContext();
      this.audioBuffer = await fetch("click.wav")
        .then(res => res.arrayBuffer())
        .then(arrayBuffer => 
          this.audioContext.decodeAudioData(arrayBuffer)
        )
    }
}
```

This is what I tried. The problem I have is that the state being async on React won't update while the function is running and the value of `playing` will never change.

```
const firstRender = useRef(true);
const [bpm, setBpm] = useState<number>(60);
const [playing, setPlaying] = useState<boolean>(false);
const [context, setContext] = useState<AudioContext>(undefined);
const [buffer, setBuffer] = useState<AudioBuffer>(undefined);
const [currentTime, setCurrentTime] = useState<number>(0);

useEffect(() => {
    if (firstRender.current) {
        firstRender.current = false;
        initContext();
        return;
    }
});

const toggle = () => {
    if (!playing) {
        setCurrentTime(context.currentTime);
        setPlaying(true);
        play();
    } else {
        setPlaying(false)
    }
}
  
const play = () => {
    setCurrentTime(currentTime + 60 / bpm);
    let source = context.createBufferSource();
    source.buffer = buffer;
    source.connect(context.destination);
    source.onended = playing ? play : undefined;
    source.start(currentTime);
}

const initContext = async () => {
    const audioContext = new AudioContext();
    const audioBuffer = await fetch("click.wav")
        .then(res => res.arrayBuffer())
        .then(arrayBuffer => 
            audioContext.decodeAudioData(arrayBuffer)
        )
    
    setContext(audioContext);
    setBuffer(audioBuffer);
}
```

I guess the solution should be on useEffect but I could not manage to recreate it. Any suggestion is appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! People will help, but only if you show clearly what you have tried and what goes wrong. Can you show the React code that you have tried? Ideally using the "<>" icon which allows you to add runnable code.

Comment: well i'll give you a scenario you have a state variable that's set to true by default and you are calling an api to update that state the api fetches the data  updating the state causing the component to re-render calling the api(again) updating the state setStateValue(); for example and it goes on and on 
useEffect got 2 parameters one is the function you want to run and the other is a depencies array [stateValue] if state value is the same as it was from the last render useeffect function won't run